# Saving Javascript variables for a selenium window session

Tags: javascript, selenium, webdriverwait

I'm trying to insert javascript variables using selenium javascript executor. I'm trying to access hooks for XHR so that I can write a custom webdriver wait function. below is the snippet I used

```
window.processFlag = -1;
var open = window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open,
    send = window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;

function openReplacement(method,url,async,user,password) {
    this._url = url;
    return open.apply(this,arguments);
}

function sendReplacement(data){
    if(this.onreadystatechange){
        this._onreadystatechange = this.onreadystatechange;
    }
    console.log('Request Sent');
    this.onreadystatechange = onReadyStateChangeReplacement;
    window.processFlag = 0;
    return send.apply(this,arguments);
}

function onReadyStateChangeReplacement(){
    window.processFlag = this.readyState;
    console.log('Ready State changed to : ',this.readyState);
    console.log('process Flag : ',window.processFlag);
    console.log('boolean check : ',window.processFlag ===4 );
    console.log('document readystate : ',document.readyState);
    if(this._onreadystatechange){
        return this._onreadystatechange.apply(this,arguments);
    }
}

window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = openReplacement;
window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = sendReplacement;
```

And I'm using window.processFlag == 4 as the condition for my WebDriverWait function

and I'm calling this snippet after launching the site. But, If the page is refreshed or at certain element clicks, the variables are getting undefined. Is there anyway we can make these variables persistent throughout the selenium window session? Thanks in advance

Comment: You could set them in localStorage...

Comment: I tried that, But it's not working when the page gets refreshed :-(

Comment: right, you would have to reload them from localStorage / sessionStorage after every navigation